# AtomicParsley - Get STCO Entries only

Tags: mp4, mp4box, parser

So I want [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) to list all of the STCO entries instead of showing something like this

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 32, ends @ 32
Atom free @ 32 of size: 8, ends @ 40
Atom mdat @ 40 of size: 137612127, ends @ 137612167
Atom moov @ 137612167 of size: 910747, ends @ 138522914
     Atom mvhd @ 137612175 of size: 108, ends @ 137612283
     Atom trak @ 137612283 of size: 358217, ends @ 137970500
         Atom tkhd @ 137612291 of size: 92, ends @ 137612383
         Atom edts @ 137612383 of size: 36, ends @ 137612419
             Atom elst @ 137612391 of size: 28, ends @ 137612419
         Atom mdia @ 137612419 of size: 358081, ends @ 137970500
             Atom mdhd @ 137612427 of size: 32, ends @ 137612459
             Atom hdlr @ 137612459 of size: 45, ends @ 137612504
             Atom minf @ 137612504 of size: 357996, ends @ 137970500
                 Atom vmhd @ 137612512 of size: 20, ends @ 137612532
                 Atom dinf @ 137612532 of size: 36, ends @ 137612568
                     Atom dref @ 137612540 of size: 28, ends @ 137612568
                 Atom stbl @ 137612568 of size: 357932, ends @ 137970500
                     Atom stsd @ 137612576 of size: 152, ends @ 137612728
                         Atom avc1 @ 137612592 of size: 136, ends @ 137612728
                             Atom avcC @ 137612678 of size: 50, ends @ 137612728
                     Atom stts @ 137612728 of size: 24, ends @ 137612752
                     Atom stss @ 137612752 of size: 700, ends @ 137613452
                     Atom ctts @ 137613452 of size: 138808, ends @ 137752260
                     Atom stsc @ 137752260 of size: 40, ends @ 137752300
                     Atom stsz @ 137752300 of size: 109104, ends @ 137861404
                     Atom stco @ 137861404 of size: 109096, ends @ 137970500
     Atom trak @ 137970500 of size: 552316, ends @ 138522816
         Atom tkhd @ 137970508 of size: 92, ends @ 137970600
         Atom edts @ 137970600 of size: 36, ends @ 137970636
             Atom elst @ 137970608 of size: 28, ends @ 137970636
         Atom mdia @ 137970636 of size: 552180, ends @ 138522816
             Atom mdhd @ 137970644 of size: 32, ends @ 137970676
             Atom hdlr @ 137970676 of size: 45, ends @ 137970721
             Atom minf @ 137970721 of size: 552095, ends @ 138522816
                 Atom smhd @ 137970729 of size: 16, ends @ 137970745
                 Atom dinf @ 137970745 of size: 36, ends @ 137970781
                     Atom dref @ 137970753 of size: 28, ends @ 137970781
                 Atom stbl @ 137970781 of size: 552035, ends @ 138522816
                     Atom stsd @ 137970789 of size: 103, ends @ 137970892
                         Atom mp4a @ 137970805 of size: 87, ends @ 137970892
                             Atom esds @ 137970841 of size: 51, ends @ 137970892
                     Atom stts @ 137970892 of size: 24, ends @ 137970916
                     Atom stsc @ 137970916 of size: 286024, ends @ 138256940
                     Atom stsz @ 138256940 of size: 156780, ends @ 138413720
                     Atom stco @ 138413720 of size: 109096, ends @ 138522816
     Atom udta @ 138522816 of size: 98, ends @ 138522914
         Atom meta @ 138522824 of size: 90, ends @ 138522914
             Atom hdlr @ 138522836 of size: 33, ends @ 138522869
             Atom ilst @ 138522869 of size: 45, ends @ 138522914
                 Atom ©too @ 138522877 of size: 37, ends @ 138522914
                     Atom data @ 138522885 of size: 29, ends @ 138522914
```

Is there anyway to show to the chunkoffset values only? I just want the STCO values.

Comment: So just lines reading ` Atom stco @ 137861404 of size: 109096, ends @ 137970500` and such or do you need to narrow it further ? Feels like you can do some clever stuff with grep and cut.

Comment: No I need to list all of the STCO entries. All of the chunk offset values.

Comment: Not `Atom stco @ 137861404 of size: 109096, ends @ 137970500`. @JourneymanGeek